# Resolve response headers from query in ui route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out how to move a query from controller to resolve in route.

Right now I have this in my controller to get some projects and the projects count by a some search/criteria object (for pagination purpose)

```
Projects.query( *{some crit}* ,function (projects, getResponseHeaders) {
    $scope.projects = projects;
    $scope.projectsCount = getResponseHeaders('x-total-count');
});
```

now, i want this query to be resolved in the ui router, so i will have 'projects' and 'projectsCount' resolved to the controller already... how can it be done?

```
.state('manage.projects', {
    url: '/projects',
    controller: 'ProjectsController',
    templateUrl: 'projects.html',
    resolve: {
        projects: function (Projects) {
            return Projects.query(*{some crit}*).$promise; (?????)
        },
        projectsCount: function () {
            (??????)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response headers should be metadata, but sometimes that's still necessary, like the ETag header.  You could do something simple like `$scope.projectsCount = $scope.projects.length;`

If you absolutely want to do it the way you posted, I suggest wrapping your resolved values in an object because 1) it requires less code modification when adding resolved data and 2) it's pretty much necessary in your situation so you don't make your service call twice.

```
.state('manage.projects', {
    url: '/projects',
    controller: 'ProjectsController',
    templateUrl: 'projects.html',
    // 'resolve' functions need to return Q promises, not jQuery promises.
    resolve: {
        baseDataResolved: ['$log', '$q', 'Projects', function ($log, $q, Projects) {
            var qDeferred = new $q.defer();
            // Assuming your 'Projects.query' returns a jQuery promise.
            Projects.query(*{some crit}*)
            .done( function success( responseData, status_text, jqXHR ) {
                var baseData = {
                    'projects':responseData,
                    'projectsCount':jqXHR.getResponseHeader('x-total-count'),
                };
                qDeferred.resolve( baseData );
            })
            .fail(function failure( jqXHR, status_text, error_thrown ) {
                $log.error( error_thrown );
                qDeferred.reject( error_thrown );
            });
            return( qDeferred.promise );
        }],
    }
})
```